# Split game Into Parts

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I have a big game (mobile) divided into different parts is it possible to build a small version and make the user only download certain part ?like for example creating different games and he can download some

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.20/manual/AddressableAssetsGettingStarted.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complicated but it's possible.
I don't write code because it would be endless work, but I give you some guidelines:

### Asset bundles

Asset bundle is a way to very compress all your assets except scripts.
Basically you can think of it as zip files, which you can unzip and use whenever you want.
For example you can insert all the assets of a specific minigame, such as textures, 3D models, sprites, audio files and the rest.
When the user wants to play a minigame, you will have to unzip it.
You can also show a screen showing the upload percentage.

### Firebase Storage

Asset bundles save you a lot of space, but if you need to save even more space, you can upload them to a server and the user will download the asset bundle from the server.
Obviously it will take a little longer than to recall it from memory;  moreover, he will not be able to download it and then play it if he is offline.
To upload your asset bundles, I can recommend the Firebase Storage service.
You will not pay anything for a long time because you have 5gb free and in a month you can download it seems to me up to 1gb totally free.
Alternatively you can rent a normal server.

**if you think my answer helped you, you can mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). I would very much appreciate it :)**

Comment: Oh I'm very glad I helped you. If you need help with Asset Bundels, you can ask another question and I will gladly answer you, as they are not a very easy subject to understand. If you want to help me help more people, you can rate my question positively :)